# How to turn ADB TCPIP on without USB cable

Tags: android, wifi, adb

is it possible on an Android device to start adb in tcpip mode programmatically?
On default it is in usb mode and I have to connect it to my pc via cable to make it listen on tcpip connections.

But I dont want to use a cable every time. How can this be done from an app without root access?

Thanks

Comment: On a normal, secured device it can't.  But atypical devices may come with it already on.